# D3. Create an Image Cloud with D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Im trying to create an Image Cloud component like the one in the image.
[image: Example]

I've tried using a simple d3 alorithm with rects and force to center the images and to spread them with collisions. The problem is that it looks like this:

[image: My attempt]

The images look too far apart one of each other, and even with lower collition radius the cloud doesn't use all avaliable space (fit smaller images between gaps). Is it there a way to make this component with the layouts given by d3? should I modify some other layout? I know I can implement an square collition force, but the results doesnt look as the one desired.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you very much.

EDIT: Hello again. I finally made it look somewhat similar to the desired result.
Sadly, now I have more problems. The first and most important one: the big images should be close one of each other and should be as centered as possible.

The second one: Im using React, and my data comes from calling the exported render function from outside the file (see first code snippet), the problem is that when I update the data, the image just dissapears and it doesn't adjust the layout again. How can i make it update it? A temporary hack that I made is to remove every image and rect from the DOM before rendering.

Again, thank you for your time.

Edit: I managed to get everything like I wanted. There is still room for improvement but this is functional for now. I managed to get an observer for the div and a somewhat good state management with React. Someday I will upload the react component to github

```
// specify svg width and height;
const width = 500, height = 500;
const listenTo = Math.min(width, height);
// create svg and g DOM elements;
let svg = d3.select('body')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('xmlns', 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg')
  .attr('width', listenTo)
  .attr('height', listenTo)
  .append('g')
  // move 0,0 to the center
  .attr('transform', `translate(${width >>1}, ${height>>1})`);

var images = [], maxImages = 100, maxWeight = 50, minWeight = 1, padding=3;
for(let i = 0; i< maxImages -1; i++){
const weight = (Math.random() *(maxWeight - minWeight)) + minWeight;
  images.push({
    url:`https://via.placeholder.com/100?text=${Math.ceil(weight)}`,
    weight
  })
}
// make one image with a weight 3 times bigger for visualization testing propouses
images.push({
  url: `https://via.placeholder.com/100?text=${maxWeight * 3}`,
  weight: maxWeight * 3,
  fx: 0,
  fy: 0
})
images.sort((a, b) => b.weight - a.weight);

// make it so the biggest images is equal to 10% of canvas, and thre smallest one 1%
const scl = ((100 / maxImages) / 100);
console.log(scl);
const maxImageSize = listenTo * 0.1;
const minImageSize = listenTo * scl;

// function to scale the images
const scaleSize = d3.scaleLinear().domain([minWeight, maxWeight*3]).range([minImageSize, maxImageSize]).clamp(true);

// append the rects
let vizImages = svg.selectAll('.image-cloud-image')
  .data(images)
  .enter()
  .append('svg:image')
  .attr('class', '.image-cloud-image')
  .attr('height', d => scaleSize(d.weight))
  .attr('width', d => scaleSize(d.weight))
  .attr('id', d => d.url)
  .attr('xlink:href', d => d.url);
  vizImages.exit().remove();

// create the collection of forces
const simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
  // set the nodes for the simulation to be our images
  .nodes(images)
  // set the function that will update the view on each 'tick'
  .on('tick', ticked)
  .force('center', d3.forceCenter())
  .force('cramp', d3.forceManyBody().strength(listenTo / 100))
  // collition force for rects
  .force('collide', rectCollide().size(d=> {
  const s = scaleSize(d.weight);
  return [s + padding, s + padding];
  }));

// update the position to new x and y
function ticked() {
  vizImages.attr('x', d => d.x).attr('y', d=> d.y);
}

// Rect collition algorithm. i don't know exactly how it works
// https://bl.ocks.org/cmgiven/547658968d365bcc324f3e62e175709b
function rectCollide() {
    var nodes, sizes, masses
    var size = constant([0, 0])
    var strength = 1
    var iterations = 1

    function force() {
        var node, size, mass, xi, yi
        var i = -1
        while (++i < iterations) { iterate() }

        function iterate() {
            var j = -1
            var tree = d3.quadtree(nodes, xCenter, yCenter).visitAfter(prepare)

            while (++j < nodes.length) {
                node = nodes[j]
                size = sizes[j]
                mass = masses[j]
                xi = xCenter(node)
                yi = yCenter(node)

                tree.visit(apply)
            }
        }

        function apply(quad, x0, y0, x1, y1) {
            var data = quad.data
            var xSize = (size[0] + quad.size[0]) / 2
            var ySize = (size[1] + quad.size[1]) / 2
            if (data) {
                if (data.index <= node.index) { return }

                var x = xi - xCenter(data)
                var y = yi - yCenter(data)
                var xd = Math.abs(x) - xSize
                var yd = Math.abs(y) - ySize

                if (xd < 0 && yd < 0) {
                    var l = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y)
                    var m = masses[data.index] / (mass + masses[data.index])

                    if (Math.abs(xd) < Math.abs(yd)) {
                        node.vx -= (x *= xd / l * strength) * m
                        data.vx += x * (1 - m)
                    } else {
                        node.vy -= (y *= yd / l * strength) * m
                        data.vy += y * (1 - m)
                    }
                }
            }

            return x0 > xi + xSize || y0 > yi + ySize ||
                   x1 < xi - xSize || y1 < yi - ySize
        }

        function prepare(quad) {
            if (quad.data) {
                quad.size = sizes[quad.data.index]
            } else {
                quad.size = [0, 0]
                var i = -1
                while (++i < 4) {
                    if (quad[i] && quad[i].size) {
                        quad.size[0] = Math.max(quad.size[0], quad[i].size[0])
                        quad.size[1] = Math.max(quad.size[1], quad[i].size[1])
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function xCenter(d) { return d.x + d.vx + sizes[d.index][0] / 2 }
    function yCenter(d) { return d.y + d.vy + sizes[d.index][1] / 2 }

    force.initialize = function (_) {
        sizes = (nodes = _).map(size)
        masses = sizes.map(function (d) { return d[0] * d[1] })
    }

    force.size = function (_) {
        return (arguments.length
             ? (size = typeof _ === 'function' ? _ : constant(_), force)
             : size)
    }

    force.strength = function (_) {
        return (arguments.length ? (strength = +_, force) : strength)
    }

    force.iterations = function (_) {
        return (arguments.length ? (iterations = +_, force) : iterations)
    }

    return force
  }
  function constant(_) {
    return function () { return _ }
  }
```

[Here's a fiddle for future people](https://jsfiddle.net/emngaiden/g04uwyt9/latest/)

Comment: Perhaps add a charge function for objects that is proportional to size. This should bring the large objects closer together

Comment: Hello, I finally made it so the images dont overlap. But I dont know exactly how to make the charge function proportional to size. its the same logic as the other forces? like forceX(data => data.value)? or I need to create the function from ground up?